# domain in asp.net host and subdomain in linux hosting, how do it

Tags: asp.net, host

Domain in asp.net host for exp : X.com and we want run sub domain : Y.X.com in linux hosting.

How should configure dns or other things for sub domain in asp.net hosting for link yo linux hosting?

Answer (score 1):

When they are on different IPs it's easy. If your ASP.NET machine has IP x.x.x.x then set the A record for X.com to x.x.x.x - and if your UNIX thing has IP y.y.y.y set A record for Y.X.com to y.y.y.y

Answer (score 0):

The exact process to set this up will be different depending on the management panel you have available for you to control the domain.

Technically the process would simply be to set up two DNS records, the A record for the main domain and an additional A record for the subdomain which would point at the linux server.

You would probably want to set up two more domains on top of this to support the www. prefix, and maybe even more records if you want to point ftp, webmail, etc at services.

Please either let us know what company you are using to manage the domains DNS records or alternatively go to the company themselves and ask their support department how you you can make the changes.